# How to arrive at one unified test framework which will run tests on all presentation layers - Web,Mobile App & desktop App

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, protractor, appium

**Problem Statement:** Being in Test Automation arena for quite some time, I always ran into this puzzle of how to design one integrated Test Strategy to run automated scripts across all the 3 UI layers which most latest apps support

- Mobile App - Hybrid
- Wed App - accessed through browsers
- Desktop Apps

**More Details**

Any modern application supports all the above listed platforms and their are diverse tools to test each platform

- Desktop - QTP, AutoIt libraries ....
- Web - Selenium and selenium extensions like Protractor so on, QTP ...
- Mobile App - Appium so on ..

But how do we design an effective Test Automation Framework which will involve writing the functional test case flow at one place - language agnostic and make it work across any platform that we want to execute on?

I have summarized my work so far as an answer below. Please feel free to throw around any ideas !!

Comment: I'll just leave this famous link here [The Law of Leaky Abstractions](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/). Anything you might create will be complicated enough to fit the law premises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to achieve this as per my analysis is to write language agnostic cases in BDD Style using Cucumber and have separate implementations based on the platform the tests need to run

I have summarized the complete architecture below.I have named it Panacea Framework :) I have blogged low level [details here](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2017/02/19/panacea-framework-test-automation-strategy-to-run-scripts-on-webmobile-and-desktop/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, you can use [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) for writing your tests - it has versions for Ruby, Java, JavaScript, and many other language flavors. The Cucumber/BDD approach does give you high-level language independence for the Cucumber Scenarios, but you still have to write your step definitions in your language of choice.

The Cucumber framework can run tests against any application: mobile app, mobile web, or desktop applications, regardless of the language those applications are written in (we use ruby/cucumber with various plugins to test across all three).

The support elements of Cucumber will need some customization for any broad-reaching framework (env, hooks, etc.) so that you can get good reports and make things as easy as possible for testing, but the basics are already there.

You'll need support for actually driving the tests at the low level (i.e., making clicks, swipes, etc. work): that would be [selenium-webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), or [Watir](https://github.com/watir/watir) if you prefer. There may well be other approaches. There are language-specific plugins for Selenium, so for ruby, you just add the [selenium-webdriver gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver/versions/2.53.4).

All tests can be run locally (I have implemented a series of shell scripts/functions to make this easy). Then you can use [Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci) to run Basic Acceptance Tests on a regular basis, and also for automating the CI Pipeline.

In addition, you can use [Appium and friends](https://github.com/appium) to automate your tests across Apple and Android with simulators or using real devices.

It's all open-source which is nice (if you like that sort of thing) and it meets your criteria. Most importantly its available now (and it works for us).

Answer (score 0):

> design one integrated Test Strategy to run automated scripts across all the 3 UI

BDD is not intended to be 1 to 1 with your test code implementation, otherwise, the business team won't take ownership.  Instead, link an identifier using spec/test properties to match up tests to the BDD definition.

You need page objects to be as compositional as they exist in the real application. This allows developers to create derivative tests (positive/negative) testing than just having a bag of helpers.  Example: a view contains 1 or more components, so, a feature spec could look like:

**web desktop:**

```
it('', () => {
  // protractor sample:
  const view = new View();
  const sidebar = await view.newRecord();
  const apiresult = sidebar.save({neverset: true});

  apiresult.then((data) => fail('expected bad request not a 200 from api.'), () => {});
}
```

**hybrid (media queries):**

If you are building a hybrid app define multiple configs for `chromeOptions { args: ['--window-size=1920x1080'] }` so you can test your various media query stock sizes.

**native + desktop:**

I would put my bet on the webdriver protocol,  https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#privacy , to be the magic sauce you are looking for.  Chrome browser or some mobile simulator will interpret the protocol to actions inside the mobile simulator.  Checkout how electron uses the webdriver protocol to test a desktop app: http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver/#setting-up-with-webdriverjs

Answer (score 0):

In either of the interface viz., Web App or Mobile App or Desktop(Standalone App), the main bottleneck is the maintenance effort if not designed properly.

I would use Page Object Pattern and maintain page classes and abstract the behaviour of the app from Tests.This way it makes my work easy.

Separation Of Concerns. Single Responsibility Principle.